# Google Chrome "--allow-access-from-files" mode does not work

Tags: google-chrome, filesystem, javascript, web-development

I need to run a javascript code which accesses the file system (with file:// protocol) from google chrome. I have seen it can be allowed with the so-called `--allow-access-from-files` option as explained here: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/ It works like a charm from a window computer. With my laptop on Xubuntu, I tried with:

```
google-chrome --allow-access-from-files
```

and

```
google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

but none of them seem to work. I got the unpleasant message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/me/xxx.txt Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Have the same problem :(
Work only in chromium-browser --disable-web-security

Comment: I am glad to hear I am not alone ! Thanks for the hint - I will use chromium in the meantime !